# kube-proxy failed to install iptables rule

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying kubernetes guestbook example following https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/README.md

In Step Six: I modified the json file to allow accessing the guestbook site externally. 
The modification is: replace 10.11.22.33 with my IP, and remove line ""createExternalLoadBalancer": true"

When I try `http://<my ip>:8000` in browser, the connection failed.
With some searching an debugging, I find kube-proxy failed to install iptables rule, there are error logs as below. The log also tells that install iptable rule also failed for other service.

Any suggestion?

```
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.543645     629 proxier.go:563] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-HOST rule for service "frontend"
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.543685     629 proxier.go:377] Failed to ensure portal for "frontend": error checking rule: exit status 2: iptables v1.4.21: Port `:f816:3eff:fedf:8037]:51072' not valid
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.548287     629 proxier.go:563] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-HOST rule for service "kubernetes-ro"
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.548310     629 proxier.go:377] Failed to ensure portal for "kubernetes-ro": error checking rule: exit status 2: iptables v1.4.21: Port `:f816:3eff:fedf:8037]:47447' not valid
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.555138     629 proxier.go:563] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-HOST rule for service "kubernetes"
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.555161     629 proxier.go:377] Failed to ensure portal for "kubernetes": error checking rule: exit status 2: iptables v1.4.21: Port `:f816:3eff:fedf:8037]:53103' not valid
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.560348     629 proxier.go:563] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-HOST rule for service "redis-master"
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.560366     629 proxier.go:377] Failed to ensure portal for "redis-master": error checking rule: exit status 2: iptables v1.4.21: Port `:f816:3eff:fedf:8037]:37187' not valid
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.565802     629 proxier.go:563] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-HOST rule for service "redis-slave"
Mar 19 06:23:28 centos-minion kube-proxy[629]: E0319 06:23:28.565824     629 proxier.go:377] Failed to ensure portal for "redis-slave": error checking rule: exit status 2: iptables v1.4.21: Port `:f816:3eff:fedf:8037]:55949' not valid
```

...

Comment: kue-proxy should select ipv4 address for iptables?[root@centos-minion ~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.69.117.157  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.69.117.255
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fedf:8037  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:df:80:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3018848  bytes 420803825 (401.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 10080  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1104274  bytes 160947403 (153.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you running? Some older versions have had trouble selecting host interfaces properly (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/4218).

Comment: GitVersion:"v0.9.0-391-ge335e2d3e26a9a",

 git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes.git

Comment: I downloaded code from github, compile it and upload the new kube-proxy
but now it seems the kube-proxy don't support --etcd_servers anymore.
[root@centos-minion ~]# /usr/bin/kube-proxy --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd_servers=http://centos-master:4001
unknown flag: --etcd_servers

Comment: I just noticed that --etcd_servers is removed from latest kube-proxy.
so what should use instead of --etcd_servers?

Comment: I guess I should use --master, so I launched kube-proxy with
/usr/bin/kube-proxy --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master="10.69.117.167"
this time it fails with below error, any suggestion? or I shall update whole kubernetes package instead of kube-proxy only?
I0320 09:53:08.936362    2296 proxier.go:333] Initializing iptables
I0320 09:53:08.947283    2296 server.go:95] Using API calls to get config 10.69.117.167
E0320 09:53:08.947945    2296 api.go:108] Unable to load services: Get http://10.69.117.167/api/v1beta1/services?namespace=: dial tcp 10.69.117.167:80: connection refused

Comment: I'd recommend updating the entire package.

Answer (score 1):

Some older versions of Kubernetes had trouble selecting host interfaces in certain configurations ([Issue 4218](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/4218)). It looks like that is what is going on here.

Unfortunately, the only real answer is to update to a more recent version of Kubernetes (re-deploy your cluster).